# GeometryCollection causing RuntimeError in Python

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, runtimeerror

I am trying to run a loop using my large and small polygon file, however, I experience a RuntimeError:

> RuntimeError: GDAL Error: Attempt to write non-polygon (LINESTRING)
> geometry to POLYGON type shapefile.  Failed to write record: {'id':
> '11416', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'FIDi': 1191, 'ID': 11416},
> 'geometry': {'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': [{'type':
> 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((55081...))

The loop looks something like this and what I try to do, is go through the large polygons, find each small polygon within and calculate the area. The result is a shapefile with small polygons.  However, when I try to export the file as a shapefile (`appended_concat.to_file(r'E:\...\result.shp'`) I got the error above. When I export as GPKG, everything works. I was pretty sure that polygon geometry is either `POLYGON` or `MULTIPOLYGON`, but cannot understand why I got `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

large = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\Polygons.shp')
small = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\Small_polygon.shp')
points = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\points.shp')

# check if there are any invalid geometries
list = [large, small, points]
for n in list:
    valid_gdf = n[~n.geometry.is_valid]
    print(n.shape)
    print(valid_gdf.shape)

(19726, 3)
(0, 3)
(2415, 285)
(0, 285)
(1096029, 5)
(0, 5)


appended = []

for i in large.index:

    df = small[small['FID'] == i]
    df_result = gpd.overlay(large, df, how='intersection')
    df_result['area'] = round(df_result.area / 10000, 4)
    df_result_2 = df_result[df_result['FID'] == i]
    print(df_result_2)

    appended.append(small)
    appended_concat = pd.concat(appended)
    appended_concat.to_file(r'E:\...\result.shp')

    appended_concat.to_file(r'E:\...\result.gpkg', driver='GPKG')
```

And when I import the GPKG file into QGIS, I can see that some of the polygons are GeometryCollection.

How can I transform to polygon or somehow correct the GeometryCollection figures?

[image]

Technically, I could just use the GPKG file format which does not cause the error.  However, I would like to understand why I cannot export a shapefile and why the GeometryCollection figures appears in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`intersection` process must have returned different geometries. In this case, it is usual to get GeometryCollection. For layers in the image, `intersection` may return all geometry types (point, line, polygon).

[image]
You get the error because of trying to save geometry collection as shapefile. Shapefile contains only one type of geometry.

To avoid that, use `keep_geom_type=True` in `overlay` function.

```
df_result = gpd.overlay(large, df, how='intersection', keep_geom_type=True)
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense, however, it still did not work. By running df_result = gpd.overlay(large, df, how='intersection', keep_geom_type=True) I got the same error.  I assume that problem could be with input polygons. As mentioned in GeoPandas doc: Different types can result for example from intersection of touching geometries, where two polygons intersects in a line or a point